# Role of "es" in the syntax of a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause

What is the role of "es" in the syntax of this news article sentence:

> Er behauptet, dass **es** Polizeigewalt gegen Schwarze schon immer gegeben hat.

I can write the Nebensatz without the "es" as a Hauptsatz:

> Polizeigewalt hat gegen Schwarze schon immer gegeben.

So I don't understand the role of "es" in the syntax.

Comment: Yes, you can write this, but that does not make it correct.

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't. The **es** is required in the main clause, too.

> Polizeigewalt hat **es** gegen Schwarze schon immer gegeben.

*Polizeigewalt* isn't a subject but an accusative object in this sentence. But we require a subject who does something, and that's the role of **es** here.

---

The verb **geben** requires an accusative object as many verbs do. But, it has this peculiar meaning *to exist*, and the thing which exists is an accusative object, the thing "given" (better: dropped) into the scene.

> **Es** gibt Essen.

*There is lunch (on the table.)*

Comment: You might add that it is a peculiarity of the way the word geben is used. The sentence would be correct without es if the verb existieren were used instead

Comment: I have added this explanation.

Comment: You could also mention a different order of the main clause **Es hat schon immer Polizeigewalt gegen Schwarze gegeben** This emphasizes that **Polizeigewalt** is not the subject...

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze this not-a-sentence:

> Polizeigewalt hat gegen Schwarze schon immer gegeben.

- **Polizeigewalt** (police violence)
  an accusative object (Wen hat es gegeben?)
  This is **NOT** the subject! A subject always has to stand in nominative case (details below)
- **hat ... gegeben** (did exist)
  the predicate (What is the action? What is going on in this sentence?)
- **gegen Schwarze** (against black people)
  a prepositional object (Wogegen hat es Gewalt gegeben?)
- **schon immer** (for ever)
  a predicative supplement

So we have a predicate plus supplement, and two objects. But there is no subject! *Polizeigewalt* is not the subject. By accident the nominative case and accusative case look equal at this word (which is true for most German words), but if you replace it with a masculine word, and add an article, it becomes obvious:

> wrong: **Der** Kampf hat gegen Schwarze schon immer gegeben.
>   correct: **Den** Kampf hat **es** gegen Schwarze schon immer gegeben.

The word **es** is just a grammatical placeholder for the subject. It is called "expletive subject" (if you talk about the grammatical function) or [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) (if you talk about the word class), and you have it in english too:

> **It** rains.

What is this "it" that rains? It's nothing. It's just a grammatical placeholder for the subject, and the **es** in many German sentences has exactly the same function

What also might disturb you, is the fact, that German doesn't have an SVO word order like English (SVO = Subject, Verb, Object in this sequence). German has a V2 word order (V2 = Verb at position 2), while all other parts of speech can almost freely float through the sentence.

The most common place for the subject is position 1, which results in an SVO order like english, but also other parts of speech may occupy position 1, like the accusative object *Polizeigewalt* did in your sentence.

You can move the subject to position 1, which might give you a more comfort feeling:

> **Es** hat schon immer Polizeigewalt gegen Schwarze gegeben.
>   **There** always was police violence against black people.

If you convert this sentence into *Präsens* (and delete *schon immer*, because "for ever" doesn't make much sense in present tense) you get:

> **Es** gibt Polizeigewalt gegen Schwarze.
>   **There** is police violence against black people.

And the word "there" in the english sentence also is an expletive subject. It's the same as in german. The word "there" doesn't refer to any place. I t is just a grammatical placeholder.

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "expletive subject"? Wo hast Du diesen Begriff gefunden?

Comment: @Takkat: [Hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum) werden die Begriffe *Expletivum* und *Expletiv*, und, dort wo es um die deutsche Sprache geht, auch *Subjekt-Expletiv* und ***expletives Subjekt*** synonym verwendt. Und [hier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive) gibt's das ganze auch auf englisch. Dort wird auch der englische Fachterminus ***expletive subject*** verwendet.

Comment: Ob man das vielleicht besser noch als weiterführenden Link in Deine Antwort einfügen sollte? Ich glaube nicht, dass viele unserer Leser hier damit etwas anfangen können.